# (Algorand) Single atomic transactions - is there a fee for each signed transaction?

Tags: algorand, pyteal

when grouping and sending a bunch of transactions as a single atomic transaction. Is there a fee for each signed transaction? Or 1 fee for sending them all?

ie if i am making 10 payments from my acct to 10 different recipients, do I pay 10 * my minimum txn fee for that account? Or just 1 fee?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each transaction costs 0.001 ALGO.

You can however pool the fees by setting fee to 0 on 9 and fee to 0.001x10 on one of them. The sum of fees must be Nx0.001 at minimum to cover the total cost of the atomic group.